# Ways to identify that SOLR returns empty results because of timeAllowed parameter?

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using `timeAllowed` to handle API requests to meet SLA. I assume all of my queries responds less than 2 seconds. My API sla is 5 seconds. So I set 3 seconds as `timeAllowed` parameter.

There is a growth in the data and usage pattern also changed. Hence 2 seconds sla are not matching. I do understand that SLA has to be revised.

But I would like to differentiate `timeAllowed` parameter caused 0 results and no results.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `timeAllowed` time is exceeded, the `partialResults` key will be set to true in the response:

```
"responseHeader": {
  "status": 0,
  "zkConnected": true,
  "partialResults": true,
  "QTime": 20,
  "params": {
    "q": "*:*"
  }
},
```

Be aware that this key will also be set if Solr was unable to contact one of its shards in a cloud collection - i.e. it indicates that the response returned is only the partial response, not exactly that the `timeAllowed` parameter was exceeded.

The Solr server log should however show a logged message on the `WARNING` level about the time limit being exceeded as far as I can tell from the source.